# Can Ubuntu (14.04) run full screen (2160x1440) in Hyper-v gen 2 on Surface Pro 3?

Tags: 14.04, resolution, screen, hyper-v

I was able to change the resolution to 1920x1080 by changing parameters in /etc/default/grub. But if I set the resolution to 2160x1440 (the resolution of Surface Pro 3), it does not accept this setting. I am reading everywhere that 1920x1080 is max resolution, but I don't understand why. There must be a way how to increase max resolution. Can anyone help?

Comment: I have the same problem with you, I google several hours but find no answer. Finally, I got a solution and it works well for me. You can install xrdp on the ubuntu(guest OS in Hyper V)， and then connect ubuntu by `mstsc`. Now it works in 2160x1440.